# Bash script - variable expansion within backtick/grep regex string

Tags: regex, bash, scripting, grep

I'm trying to expand a variable in my bash script inside of the backticks, inside of the regex search string.

I want the `$VAR` to be substituted.

The lines I am matching are like:

`start`....some characters.....`id:`.....some characters.....`[variable im searching for]`....some characters....`end`

```
var=`grep -E '^.*id:.*$VAR.*$' ./input_file.txt`
```

Is this a possibility?

It doesn't seem to work. I know I can normally expand a variable with `"$VAR"`, but won't this just search directly for those characters inside the regex? I am not sure what takes precedence here.

Comment: Avoid using old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses like this: `var=$(grep...... txt)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variables do expand in backticks but they don't expand in single quotes.

So you need to either use double quotes for your regex string (I'm not sure what your concern with that is about) or use both quotes.

So either

```
var=`grep -E "^.*id:.*$VAR.*$" ./input_file.txt`
```

or

```
var=`grep -E '^.*id:.*'"$VAR"'.*$' ./input_file.txt`
```

Also you might want to use `$(grep ...)` instead of backticks since they are the more modern approach and have better syntactic properties as well as being able to be nested.

Comment: Thanks, I have heard that `$()` is better, though I have also heard that the backticks are more likely to be backwards compatible. Is that also true?

Comment: Anything reasonably from this millennium should support the modern syntax.  I think even HP-UX and AIX. Certainly anything where the shell is Bash.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the expression in double quotes (and, then, escape anything which needs to be escaped) in order for the variable to be interpolated.

```
var=$(grep -E "^.*id:.*$VAR.*\$" ./input_file.txt)
```

(The backslash is not strictly necessary here, but I put it in to give you an idea.  Your real expression is perhaps more complex.)